# Where do I farm for stat potions?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I am wondering what is the best god to farm for potions.

I'm attempting my first 8/8 (knight) and I've been looking for attack and defense but don't know what gods drop them. 
Do all the gods drop them or do certain gods drop certain potions?
Where can I find the different potions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stat potions are dropped by specific enemies, some enemies can drop multiple kinds of potions.

## Attack potion

- [Beer God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/beer-god)
- [Brute of Oryx](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/oryx-s-castle-and-chamber)
- [Commander Of Oryx](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/oryx-s-castle-and-chamber)
- [Crystal Prisoner](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/crystal-prisoner)
- [Cube God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/cube-god)
- [Davy Jones](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/davy-jones)
- [Desire Troll](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/desire-troll)
- [Flying Brain](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/flying-brain)
- [Gigacorn](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/gigacorn)
- [Greater Nature Sprite](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/greater-nature-sprite)
- [Lord Ruthven](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/lord-ruthven)
- [Native Sprite God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/native-sprite-god)
- [Oryx's Simulacrum](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/oryx-the-mad-god)
- [Oryx the Mad God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/oryx-the-mad-god-2)
- [Pentaract](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/pentaract)
- [Skull Shrine](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/skull-shrine)
- [Spoiled Creampuff](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/spoiled-creampuff)
- [Sprite God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/sprite-god)
- [The Forgotten Sentinel](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/the-forgotten-sentinel)
- [Treasure Sarcophagus](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/tomb-of-the-ancients)
- [White Demon](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/white-demon)

## Defense potion

- [Abyss Idol](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/abyss-idol)
- [Archdemon Malphas](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/archdemon-malphas)
- [Beer God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/beer-god)
- [Beholder](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/beholder)
- [Brute of Oryx](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/oryx-s-castle-and-chamber)
- [Crystal Prisoner](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/crystal-prisoner)
- [Cube God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/cube-god)
- [Ent](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/ent)
- [Ent God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/ent-god)
- [Horrific Creation](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/horrific-creation)
- [Leviathan](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/leviathan)
- [Limon the Sprite God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/limon-the-sprite-god)
- [Oryx's Simulacrum](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/oryx-the-mad-god)
- [Oryx the Mad God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/oryx-the-mad-god-2)
- [Pentaract](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/pentaract)
- [Slime God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/slime-god)
- [Skull Shrine](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/skull-shrine)
- [Stone Guardian](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/stone-guardians)

## Speed potion

- [Brute of Oryx](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/oryx-s-castle-and-chamber)
- [Crystal Prisoner](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/crystal-prisoner)
- [Cube God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/cube-god)
- [Djinn](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/djinn)
- [Ghost Bride](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/ghost-bride)
- [Ghost God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/ghost-god)
- [Grave Caretaker](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/grave-caretaker)
- [Jon Bilgewater the Pirate King](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/jon-bilgewater-the-pirate-king)
- [Medusa](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/medusa)
- [Pentaract](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/pentaract)
- [Red Demon](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/red-demon)
- [Skull Shrine](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/skull-shrine)
- [Stheno The Snake Queen](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/stheno-the-snake-queen)
- [Treasure Sarcophagus](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/tomb-of-the-ancients)
- [Troll Matriarch](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/troll-matriarch)

## Dexterity potion

- [Crystal Prisoner](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/crystal-prisoner)
- [Cube God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/cube-god)
- [Hermit God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/hermit-god)
- [Jon Bilgewater the Pirate King](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/jon-bilgewater-the-pirate-king)
- [Limon the Sprite God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/limon-the-sprite-god)
- [Pentaract](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/pentaract)
- [Skull Shrine](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/skull-shrine)

## Vitality potion

- [Abyss Idol](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/abyss-idol)
- [Archdemon Malphas](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/archdemon-malphas)
- [Brute of Oryx](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/oryx-s-castle-and-chamber)
- [Crystal Prisoner](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/crystal-prisoner)
- [Cube God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/cube-god)
- [Ghost of Skuld](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/ghost-of-skuld)
- [Grand Sphinx](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/grand-sphinx)
- [Hermit God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/hermit-god)
- [Murderous Megamoth](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/murderous-megamoth)
- [Oryx the Mad God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/oryx-the-mad-god-2)
- [Pentaract](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/pentaract)
- [Skull Shrine](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/skull-shrine)

## Wisdom potion

- [Crystal Prisoner](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/crystal-prisoner)
- [Cube God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/cube-god)
- [Davy Jones](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/davy-jones)
- [Desire Troll](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/desire-troll)
- [Dr. Terrible](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/dr-terrible)
- [Ghost Bride](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/ghost-bride)
- [Gigacorn](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/gigacorn)
- [Grand Sphinx](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/grand-sphinx)
- [Grave Caretaker](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/grave-caretaker)
- [Horrific Creation](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/horrific-creation)
- [Oryx the Mad God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/oryx-the-mad-god-2)
- [Pentaract](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/pentaract)
- [Septavius the Ghost God](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/septavius-the-ghost-god)
- [Skull Shrine](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/skull-shrine)
- [Swoll Fairy](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/swoll-fairy)
- [Troll Matriarch](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/troll-matriarch)

## Life potion

- [Bes](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/bes)
- [Geb](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/geb)
- [Nut](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/nut)
- [The Forgotten King](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/the-forgotten-king)

## Mana potion

- [Son of Arachna](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/son-of-arachna)
- [Thessal the Mermaid Goddess](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/thessal-the-mermaid-goddess)
- [Twilight Archmage](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/twilight-archmage)

Source: [RealmEye wiki](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/stat-increase-potions)

Comment: I will add in the locations where you can find them tomorrow, I've been staring at this post for long enough now.